# Telegram TDLib Android : How to store apiId and apiHash?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, telegram, tdlib

I am trying to build an android telegram client using the famous [TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td).  Unfortunately, I could not find any good tutorials or documentation about using this library in android. But, I've understood how the library works from the `Java` examples.

The problem is when implementing the library, I've to pass the `api_id` and `api_hash` to `TDLib`. I think these variables must be unknown to others, as this can reused for malicious purposes.

As the documentation does not provide any best practices about storing the `api_id` and `api_hash`, How can I make them unavailable to the public and securely manage it in the android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the developer of TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/999)

> On Android the values can't be accessed without root permissions if
>   they are stored in any reasonable way. From the other side, they can
>   be extracted from the app's memory with root permissions. So you can't
>   do much besides storing them in the apps binary and obfuscating them
>   in any simple way.

and he says, **if someone extracts the key and uses it for a malicious purpose, only the user is blocked**